# Создать токены из слов между которыми нету пробелов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, работа-с-текстом, nltk

Есть признак - TOP_RANK, в котором текстом определяется признак для определённого ID клиента. Вот пример:

```
'Data: 200 F=100MB,24H'
'On net 200F=Unlimited _call24H'
'Data:1000F=5GB,7d'
'MIXT: 200mnoff net _unl on net _5Go;30d'
```

Есть предложения с пробелами а есть предложения без пробелов. Как мне лучше создать токены разделяя предложение по определённым символам, например -":", или -";"? NLTK или создаёт одно слово из признака или разделяет по словам.

Comment: Сложно так навскидку. Надо пробовать разные варианты и смотреть какой взлетит. Может тут вообще регулярками надо определённые данные вынимать из текста.

Comment: а что, одновременно по всем сразу разделителям нельзя разделять предложение?

Comment: CrazyElf,  А какие варианты то есть? Я знаю только регулярки. Одновременно по всем разделителям не желательно, из разделителей лучше оставить "," , ":" , ";"